# whenever run the batch apex job I am Getting error like "First error: Field is not writeable: ProcessInstance.Status"

Tags: apex, batch, approval-process

```java
global class TimecardApprovalBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // Query all Approval records that need to be approved
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId
            FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
            WHERE ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'
            AND ProcessInstance.TargetObject.Type = 'pse__Timecard_Header__c'
            AND DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) >= TODAY
        ]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> scope) {
        // Approve each Approval record in the scope
        List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> workitemsToApprove = new List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem>();

        for (ProcessInstanceWorkitem workitem : scope) {
            workitem.ProcessInstance.Status = 'Approved';
            workitemsToApprove.add(workitem);
        }

        // Update the Approval records
        update workitemsToApprove;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        System.debug('TimecardApprovalBatch finished.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not supposed to approve elements this way, you are supposed to submit them to approval :

```
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
      
      //Approve or Reject Record
            req.setComments('Approving request.');
            req.setAction('Approve');
            req.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {approverId});
     
      
      //Getting Work Item Id
             ProcessInstanceWorkitem pItem = [Select Id from ProcessInstanceWorkitem 
             where ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId =: appOrder.id];
     
             req.setWorkitemId(pItem.Id);
      // Submit the request for approval
             Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req);
             system.debug(result.isSuccess());
```